# kth smallest element in min heap

Tags: algorithm, c, heap

I am working on to find the kth smallest element in min heap. I have code for this whose complexity is \$O(k \log k)\$. I tried to improve it to \$O(k)\$.

```
struct heap{
     int *array;
     int count;
     int capacity;
 }

 intkthsmallestelement(struct heap *h,int i,int k){
     if(i<0||i>=h->count) 
        return INT_MIN;
     if(k==1)
       return h->array[i];
     k--;
     int j=2*i+1,k=2*i+2;
     if(h->array[j]<h->array[k])
     {
        int x=kthsmallestelement(h,j);
        if(x==INT_MIN)
           return kthsmallestelement(h,k);
        return x; 
     }
     else
     {
          int x=kthsmallestelement(h,k);
          if(x==INT_MIN)
               return kthsmallestelement(h,j);
           return x;
     }
}
```

My code is traversing k elements in heap and thus complexity is \$O(k)\$. Is it correct?

Comment: Please confirm the language choice C is right.

Comment: This isn't proper C syntax.  Either it's another language, or it's untested.

Comment: The code is broken.  The recursive calls only have 2 arguments to a function which contains 3 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Hey leave us some breathing room... :)

> ```
> if(h->array[j]<h->array[k])
> ```

should look like this

```
if(h->array[j] < h->array[k])
```

all those greater than and less than symbols can be confusing when you just wake up in the morning.  please, give them some space.

After you give everyone their space it looks like this

```
int kthsmallestelement(struct heap *h,int i,int k){
     if(i < 0 || i >= h->count) 
        return INT_MIN;
     if(k == 1)
       return h->array[i];
     k--;
     int j = 2 * i + 1, k = 2 * i + 2;
     if(h->array[j] < h->array[k])
     {
        int x= kthsmallestelement(h,j);
        if(x == INT_MIN)
           return kthsmallestelement(h,k);
        return x; 
     }
     else
     {
          int x = kthsmallestelement(h,k);
          if(x == INT_MIN)
               return kthsmallestelement(h,j);
           return x;
     }
}
```

---

all your one lined if statements can be a little confusing because you are returning inside all of them and then not leaving a new line between it and that next statement.  You should leave a newline and also use brackets for all if statements.

Then it looks like this

```
int kthsmallestelement(struct heap *h,int i,int k){
    if(i < 0 || i >= h->count) { 
        return INT_MIN;
    }

    if(k == 1) {
      return h->array[i];
    }

    k--;
    int j = 2 * i + 1, k = 2 * i + 2;
    if(h->array[j] < h->array[k])
    {
        int x= kthsmallestelement(h,j);
        if(x == INT_MIN) {
            return kthsmallestelement(h,k);
        }

        return x; 
    }
    else
    {
        int x = kthsmallestelement(h,k);
        if(x == INT_MIN) {
            return kthsmallestelement(h,j);
        }

        return x;
    }
}
```

---

I assume that your Method name is `kthesmallestelement` and not `intkthesmallestelement`.

But you should use some sort of name scheme here like PascalCasing:

```
int KthSmallestElement
```

Then you can tell what that big blob of letters says.